# How to toggle visibily of a React widget with a single HTML button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a html page like this:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<button id="toggle"></div>
```

I want to toggle the visibility of the `#app` div when the `#toggle` button is clicked.

Comment: If you want something more in a `react` way, you can try the following https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ctg8nq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery, just have a simple click handler and change the display

```js
function toggle() {
  if ($('#app').css('display') == 'none')
    $('#app').css('display', '')
  else
    $('#app').css('display', 'none')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">some stuff</div>
<button onClick="toggle()" id="toggle">toggle</button>
```

With vanilla js

```js
function toggle() {
  var el = document.getElementById('app');
  if (el.style.display == 'none') 
    el.style.display = '';
  else
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="app">some stuff</div>
<button onClick="toggle()" id="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Can you try that with vanilla JS instead. Thanks.